# Variable lengths differ error message in aov

Tags: r, anova

I'm using aov to analyse some data:

```
aovdata<-read.table("Fungus ANOVA.csv", sep=",",header=T)
detach(aovdata)
attach(aovdata)
Temp <- as.factor(Temp) ; Food <- as.factor(Food)
summary(aov(Area ~ Temp*Food))
```

[The data in question appears like this in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaWNe.png)

And the error message keeps being displayed:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Area ~ Temp * Food,
> drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :    variable lengths differ (found for
> 'Temp')

The rest of my script is this:

```
interaction.plot(Temp, Food, Area, xlab = "Temperature", ylab = "Area", trace.label = "Food", las = 1, xtick = TRUE, cex.lab = 1.3)
bartlett.test(Area ~ interaction(Temp, Food))
shapiro.test(resid(aov(Area ~ Temp*Food)))
detach(aovdata)
attach(aovdata)
plot(Temp, Area, xlab="Temperature", ylab="Area")
par(mfrow = c(2,2)) ; plot(aov(Area ~ Temp))
```

I'm new to R and the analyses are copied from another, working script that used a data set of the same size so I have no idea what is wrong.